# How do I append to multiple cells in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

For example:

If the cell's value is "ABC", I want to append "D" to it.

Suppose I have a huge list and this cell with this exact value is random throughout the list. How do I reliably append to this list?

Comment: Do want the cell currently with a value of `ABC` to have the value `ABCD`? If yes, you will need VBA. If the `CONCATENATE`d value can be in another cell, then you can use a formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this short VBA macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Cells.Replace What:="ABC", Replacement:="ABCD", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

If you want to restrict the change to those cells whose value is **exactly**

ABC

then use:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Cells.Replace What:="ABC", Replacement:="ABCD", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

`Macro2()` will ignore a cell like:

<kbd>Easy as ABC</kbd>

Comment: I think OP wants to consider cells with only exact value ABC. I guess your macro is generic. It will even replace ABCF with ABCDF if I am not wrong. Do comment/confirm. Thanks

Comment: @pat2015  See my **EDIT#1**

Answer (score -1):

How about the Find and Replace option (I'm looking in Excel 2016) ?
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90